# Covariance Matrix of Correlated Random Variable

Tags: options, implied-volatility, correlation, variance, covariance

Suppose I know or have estimated the covariance matrix for one random variable (for example an asset) and have:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
<\text{spot, spot}> & <\text{atmv, spot}> \\
<\text{spot, atmv}> & <\text{atmv, atmv}>
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where atmv is the at the money volatility (or can just be realized).
Suppose then I know the beta or correlation of this asset A to asset B. How would you derive the covariance matrix B as a function of beta and covariance matrix for A?

Comment: you say the covariance matrix for one random variable but you need to view atmv as another random variable. So, you actually have three random variables. asset A, asset B and atmv.  So, when you say covariance matrix of B, what is the random variable  that B is correlated with ?

Answer (score 0):

$return(b)=cor_{A,B}*return(A)+noise_1$
so

$return(b)=cor_{A,B}*(beta_{A,vol}*atmvol+noise_2)+noise_1$

so the correlation between b and atm vol depends on the correlation assumption between atmvol and noise_1. So there's no right answer if you have to go through A. Why don't you just directly correlate atmvol and asset B?

Note $cor_{A,B}$ is the correlation multiplied by the ratio of standard deviations of A and B (usual relationship between regression beta and correlation coefficient)

Comment: Arshdeep: I think you meant to write $\beta_{A,B}$ whereever you have written $cor_{A,B}$ above. Still, it's an insightful answer. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds yes I've clarified the notation in my comment, I was just being lazy and thought the point would be apparent either way.

Comment: No problem. But, in the first two formulae, it should be changed also.

Comment: Even if the notation has been clarified, denoting beta as cor is unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: Whats the issue with simply assuming E(noise_1) = E(noise_2) = 0?

Comment: @roz: In a simple univariate OLS setting, which is what Arshdeep assumed when he wrote those equations, the error term is usually assumed to be normally distributed with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$. Note that, as I mentioned earlier, you have 3 random variables, so the RHS of the regression should really contain atmvol and return so no longer simple OLS. Arshdeep wrote it recursively which meant two OLS's that he combined but that's not really the way one would proceed. Still, it was a good idea what he did.

Comment: I've only assumed normality of everything. Then what look like regression equations are actually cholesky decompositions.